# Gitignore files meteor

Tags: meteor

I get this error

```
While selecting package versions:                                                              
error: unknown package in top-level dependencies: : font-awesome
```

font-awesome is listed the the project gitignore file. The package is about 1 &1/2 years old

Comment: How are you getting this error? Is it when you run meteor? What does your .meteor/packages file look like?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, you have added a package called `font-awesome`. You can add the real Font Awesome package using `meteor add fortawesome:fontawesome`. You may have to go to your `.meteor/packages` file and remove the line that says `font-awesome`.

Check out the [Atmosphere](https://atmospherejs.com/fortawesome/fontawesome) page for more information on how to install and use the Font Awesome package in Meteor.